# Custom layout in dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, android-xml

There is an issue appears when I collected the data to display them at my dialog - I called **My dialog data**. When I have large data I wanted to display them at the TextView (Down the TextView that says **Peaks in KPa and Time in sec.** The data will append all the way down and cover the two buttons - The is an issue in my XML desgin that  I couldn't figure it out. 
I want the TextView that displays the Peaks and time to be as a ListView, so as much as I have data, they will display without an issue. 
Could you please help me out how to redesign the textview to be in a good shape ListView. 
The problem is I have tried several time to play with XML and make ListView instead of these TextViews (I'm talking about **android:text="Peaks"** and **android:text="@string/Peaks_index"**, but I couldn't.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2196F3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:text="@string/PeaksinKPa"
            android:textColor="#040307" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:text="time in sec."
            android:textColor="#040307" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2196F3"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Peak_Num"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:text="Peaks"
            android:textColor="#040307" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_Index"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:text="@string/Peaks_index"
            android:textColor="#040307" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        android:padding="3dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Del"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Delete File"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:layout_margin="1dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_margin="1dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The issue is explained in pictures. [image: here is my issue]

[image: this is when there is no data in]

Comment: You need a Custom Adapter in which one "row" displays two textviews in a ListView. You should not load a LinearLayout of TextViews.

Comment: Please would you mind to write a pseudo xml for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need Java code more than XML. Please refer to [Using a CustomArrayAdapter](http://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#using-a-custom-arrayadapter)

Comment: that is way too much. I would prefer to make new activity and make these two TextView as one TableView. I need the best easiest way. No restriction. If you could advise me with easy way instead of making dialog, I would go through it. I think that is a bit pain.

Comment: If you want a scrollable view that doesn't expand to the whole device, then put in a ScrollView. If you want to do it correctly, then you should use a ListView with a Custom Adapter.

Comment: simple listview with two textviews would be enough.!

Comment: Thanks @Dhina. The problem has been solved.